# Chip inside select field in material ui and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i'm having a little issue here and i need your help.
I want to render a select field with chip inside of it. I successfully implement this but i'm having a little issue. When i click in one of my chip inside the dropdown the dropdown text is showing nothing. I add the propery primaryText inside the menu item and the value is shown successfully but not with the way i wish. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
          <MenuItem
            key={id}
            value={id}
            style={styles.scroll}
            primaryText={id}
          >
            <Chip
              key={id}
              style={styles.chip}
              onClick={() => customerSessionSelector(id)}
              onRequestDelete={() => handleRequestDelete(id)}
            >
              {id}
            </Chip>
          </MenuItem>
```

For not showing the text under the chip i remove the primaryText property but when i select the value the value is now showing? Any ideas of how to achieve something like this?

Comment: Will you please create plnkr of jsfiddle foe this ?

Comment: Can you please explain more detaily what you try to archive? Something like this?   
https://sharlaan.github.io/material-ui-superselectfield/

Comment: How did you solve this?